# error installing by using this command npm install react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm doing a project and when I try to use this command, this error pops up and installation is failed. I tried many times using different commands too.

This is the error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\AMMA\Desktop\crowdfunding\client\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:865
npm ERR!   const err = new Error(message);
npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\AMMA\Desktop\crowdfunding\client\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild --version
npm ERR! node:child_process:929
npm ERR!     throw err;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync C:\Users\AMMA\Desktop\crowdfunding\client\node_modules\esbuild-windows-64\esbuild.exe UNKNOWN
npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1124:20)
npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:876:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:919:15)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AMMA\Desktop\crowdfunding\client\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild:211:28)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
npm ERR!   errno: -4094,
npm ERR!   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync C:\\Users\\AMMA\\Desktop\\crowdfunding\\client\\node_modules\\esbuild-windows-64\\esbuild.exe', 
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\AMMA\\Desktop\\crowdfunding\\client\\node_modules\\esbuild-windows-64\\esbuild.exe',
npm ERR!   spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
npm ERR!   error: [Circular *1],
npm ERR!   status: null,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: null,
npm ERR!   pid: 0,
npm ERR!   stdout: null,
npm ERR!   stderr: null
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.7.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:890:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:926:15)
npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (C:\Users\AMMA\Desktop\crowdfunding\client\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:90:32)        
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\AMMA\Desktop\crowdfunding\client\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:241:5 {
npm ERR!   status: 1,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: [
npm ERR!     null,
npm ERR!     Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
npm ERR!     Buffer(1290) [Uint8Array] [
npm ERR!       110, 111, 100, 101,  58,  99, 104, 105, 108, 100,  95, 112,
npm ERR!       114, 111,  99, 101, 115, 115,  58,  57,  50,  57,  13,  10,
npm ERR!        32,  32,  32,  32, 116, 104, 114, 111, 119,  32, 101, 114,
npm ERR!       114,  59,  13,  10,  32,  32,  32,  32,  94,  13,  10,  13,
npm ERR!        10,  60, 114, 101, 102,  32,  42,  49,  62,  32,  69, 114,
npm ERR!       114, 111, 114,  58,  32, 115, 112,  97, 119, 110,  83, 121,
npm ERR!       110,  99,  32,  67,  58,  92,  85, 115, 101, 114, 115,  92,
npm ERR!        65,  77,  77,  65,  92,  68, 101, 115, 107, 116, 111, 112,
npm ERR!        92,  99, 114, 111,
npm ERR!       ... 1190 more items
npm ERR!     ]
npm ERR!   ],
npm ERR!   pid: 19568,
npm ERR!   stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
npm ERR!   stderr: Buffer(1290) [Uint8Array] [
npm ERR!     110, 111, 100, 101,  58,  99, 104, 105, 108, 100,  95, 112,
npm ERR!     114, 111,  99, 101, 115, 115,  58,  57,  50,  57,  13,  10,
npm ERR!      32,  32,  32,  32, 116, 104, 114, 111, 119,  32, 101, 114,
npm ERR!     114,  59,  13,  10,  32,  32,  32,  32,  94,  13,  10,  13,
npm ERR!      10,  60, 114, 101, 102,  32,  42,  49,  62,  32,  69, 114,
npm ERR!     114, 111, 114,  58,  32, 115, 112,  97, 119, 110,  83, 121,
npm ERR!     110,  99,  32,  67,  58,  92,  85, 115, 101, 114, 115,  92,
npm ERR!      65,  77,  77,  65,  92,  68, 101, 115, 107, 116, 111, 112,
npm ERR!      92,  99, 114, 111,
npm ERR!     ... 1190 more items
npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.7.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AMMA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-15T18_05_00_777Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Are you doing react-router-dom ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider downgrading your Node.js version to the latest stable release. It appears you're currently on Node.js v20.7.0, which is still in development. I recommend using Node.js version 18.18.2 for installing it via the command `npm i react-router-dom`. I've tested it with this configuration, and it worked for me.